superset drill down option on chart
Is it possible to create a drill down graph with apache superset? for example - population of all countries and onclick of a country, population of all states within that country should be drawn and onclick of state, population of state should be drawn. Can someone help me with steps/tips to create this using apache superset as I did not find any example/option to create the same.

i was expecting the drill down/ drill option in the graph using superset


Superset does not have drill down feature as yet.
As a work-around, you can use multiple charts for each levels (country, state etc) and use filters to view data for required countries, states etc.
You can customize filter-scoping so that it works somewhat similar to your needs.
